# POST a list of items using REST

Tags: rest, post

I'm looking for a convention on how to serialize my data when I have a (long) list of items that I want to POST to the server.

For example, if I have a resource `/users` and I wanted to POST a new one to it, I'd http-encode the fields for the new user and put it in the request body like this: `name=foo&age=20`

But if I have a list of users, like this `[{ name: 'foo', age: 20 }, { name: 'bar', age: 10 }]`, is there a conventional way of POSTing this?

I'm thinking `name[0]=foo&age[0]=20&name[1]=bar&age[1]=10` but I can't find anything to back it up. What do web servers usually accept/expect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quick question which may change my answer: Are you POSTing directly from an HTML form or are you expecting something more sophisticated (e.g. javascript processsing, or not even a web-based client)

If you have a sophisticated enough client, you could just construct a JSON string and POST with a content type of `application/json`. Then whatever resource is processing the POST could use any number of json libraries to read the posted string and process as is.

#### Further Rambling:

What framework/languages are you using to construct your REST service? Do they have built-in functionality/conventions to help you?

For example if you're using JAX-RS to build your service, there is a built in annotation [@FormParam](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html) which can be used to process posted forms... for example: if you posted the following with a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: `name=foo&age=20&name=bar&age=10`

You could retrieve parallel lists on the service side via:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public void createUsers(@FormParam("name") List<String> name, @FormParam("age") List<String> age) {
    // Store your users
}
```

But you would then have to deal with the question of what if one list is shorter/longer than the other, how do you resolve that? What happens if a new field is required or optional to create a list of users? (But as I mentioned initially, a JSON array of JSON objects would solve that issue... there are a number of libraries out there that support automagic JSON deserialization in JAX-RS or there is also the option of creating your own [MessageBodyReader](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html).

(Disclaimer on the next section: I don't know rails, my experience is more in the Java services world... I'm basing this on [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)). It looks like Rails has a convention of `name[]=foo&name[]=bar` to process posted data into arrays automagically, and a similar convention to populate structure like `user[name]=foo&user[age]=20`... Perhaps if you are on rails there is some way to use/abuse both of these features to get the desired result?

Other REST frameworks and languages may have their own conventions and functionality :)

Comment: It's more sophisticated than an HTML form. I can do any kind of processing before sending it. I've considered serializing the data as JSON, just as you're suggesting, but I'm uncertain if it's conventional. If what you're saying is common then it's definitely one way to go. My gut feeling tells me JSON is even a little too generic, as the data is never nested deeper than in my example though. Some example of how this have been solved before would great!

Comment: Sorry, I was engrossed in rambling more and just saw your comment. :) The tl;dr; version of my second point in my post: Have you landed on a framework for your REST services? Do they have a built in convention for such things (which would make your life easier)?

Comment: ach_l has a very good point in that the most important thing is what your server side will accept (which sort of implies that there is no real standard for this kind of thing -- I don't think the people who wrote the spec back in the pioneering age of the web foresaw hierarchical content).

Answer (score 1):

Rails serializes forms on a format not unlike what you suggest. If you have a nested model it encodes it like this:

```
name=theo&company[name]=acme
```

(the equivalent JSON would be `{"name": "theo", "company": {"name": "acme"}}`)

I can't say that I've seen a Rails application sending arrays, but there's no reason why it wouldn't work (worst case you would end up with a hash with string keys).

PHP has another convention, if you want to send an array you do

```
names[]=alice&names[]=bob&names[]=steve
```

But I don't know how you do nested objects that way.

The HTTP spec, or if it's the URI spec, not sure which atm, actually specifies that if you pass the same argument multiple times you get array of values (instead of the last-wins behaviour of most application frameworks). You can see this in the API docs for Jetty, for example: http://api.dpml.net/org/mortbay/jetty/6.1.5/org/mortbay/jetty/Request.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)

However, most of this applies to `GET` requests, not necessarily `POST` (but perhaps `application/x-url-encoded` should adhere to the same standards as `GET`).

In short, I don't think there is *a* standard for doing this, `POST` bodies are a bit of a wild west territory. I think, however, that either you should go with JSON, because it's made to describe structures, and `application/x-url-encoded` is not, or you should try to represent the structure of your data better, something like:

```
users[0][name]=foo&users[0][age]=20&users[1][name]=bar&users[1][age]=10
```

That has some kind of chance of actually being interpretable by a Rails app out of the box, for example.