# REST - Post a JSON list, or multiple Posts?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api

Given two models: a `Person`, which has any number of `Jobs`, what is the most REST-ful way of submitting a new Person with his list of jobs?

The two obvious options that come to me are to JSON-ify the Person object with his list of Jobs.

```
"{"name":"ngmiceli",
  "jobs":[
      {"info":"foobar"},
      {"info":"lorem ipsum"},
      {"info":"ni!"}]}"
```

Stick that in the body, send the Post request, and be on your way.

The second obvious model would be much more broken up.

- Post a new Person with `"name"="ngmiceli"`
- Post a new Job to that person.  (Repeat 3x)

There will be an API controller for both of these actions separately, but if the purpose of this application is on jobs, and a person is fairly meaningless (or even invalid) without jobs, wouldn't it make sense to submit the model of the peron *with* his/her jobs?

Finally, I read about batch updates, where you send a list of Post requests that make up the second option, but in a single batched Post.

If it matters, the requests are being generated by javascript and handled in C# web-api, and are communicating with a database via entity framework.

Comment: Note: I read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194781/post-a-list-of-items-using-rest) post, but due to the context it doesn't really answer my question

Comment: First model is fine provided *you* are fine with it.

Comment: There's nothing un-RESTful about doing it in one go. I would create a method that would consume the person and the job-list to keep the over-head of the POSTs to the server to a minimum. Server-side I would of course keep it separated.

Comment: Make it optional. In the PayPal API, when getting a Transaction, you can get the whole User object, or just a simple version of it by simply passing an additional parameter. Could be something you could look into doing?

Comment: I suppose my concern was that passing a conglomerate item like that, with a list in it, was un-restful but the general consensus here is that there's nothing wrong with it. Thanks all; let me know if I misunderstood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing un-RESTful about number 1. Even if the application is not Person-centered, a Person is a valid resource in your application.

Go for the simpler solution.