# How to post a list of object using JAX-RS (to perform bean validation)

Tags: java, rest, post, jax-rs

How can I post a list of items using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type ?

For example, I would like to send a `List` of :

```
public class Person {
  @NotNull
  private String name;
  private int age;
  // getter/setter...
}
```

And this is my rest service definition :

```
@POST
@Path("/persons")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String createPersons(@Valid @FormParam("schedules") List<Person> persons) {
    return "OK";
}
```

But it seems not being accepted by jersey (no injection...). How can I pass non-primitive list of data with JAX-RS ?

Post data looks like that :
`persons[0][name]=Test&persons[0][age]=45&persons[1][name]=Test2&persons[1][age]=22`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST a list of items using REST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194781/post-a-list-of-items-using-rest)

Comment: No response in this post. I don't want to process my items as separate list of primitive type (for example, I need to use bean validation using [@Valid](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Valid.html) annotation).

Comment: Why `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Why not JSON in the body?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@BeanParam` on your `@POST` Listener.

```
public String createPersons(@Valid @BeanParam List<Person> persons) {
  return "OK";
}
```

But you have to make sure your `Person` has `@FormParam` annotation for each fields.